# wxPython TextCtrl Transparent Background

Tags: python, wxwidgets

How can I make a TextCtrl have a transparent background? By this I mean see the desktop behind it.

Current Code:

```
self.control.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Color(0,0,0,0))
```

But that just makes the background colour black.

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge `textCtrt` can't be transparent or use a background image, but you can change the background color.

**TIP:**

You can use the exact color as your background image by finding out the exact HEX color value.

**Example code:**

```
self.SetBackgroundColour('#232321')
```